# Migrating linux (madm) RAID1 (mirror) to something else?

Tags: linux, migration, software-raid

I have 2x 3TB in a mirrored RAID 1 volume. I would like to extend this to a 4x drive volume. I'd like to have 1 disk for redundancy.

I'm no IO/RAID expert, or madm come to that, but know enough to get round.

Can anyone advise on best RAID config (performance vs space - it's only a home office NAS that doubles as HTPC)? how i can migrate to new config without losing my existing data?

And also, is it possible to configure linux to email me when a disk fails?

Comment: If you have four disks and want to use one for redundancy, that doesn't leave us with a lot of options to evaluate for performance vs space does it? (Because number of drives is fixed, number of parity drives is fixed, and space is fixed.)

Comment: You can try to use a raid5 with 4 disks (3x3TB for data, 1 disk for parity, about 8TB usable). Raid5 is about 20% less performant than raid1, but you will save a lot of space. You can't convert your data from a raid1 to a raid10/5 without losing your data. You should save the integrality before doing any change. If you need more i/o you can try a raid10 (5TB usable).

Comment: Don't do this.  Just don't.  RAID-5 with discs that large is asking for catastrophic data loss down the road; search on SF for all the "*two HDDs died in my RAID-5, how can I get my data back*" questions.  If your data is of any value to you, buy enough disc space to do RAID-10.

Comment: ok, not sure why the down vote.  maybe i'm not clever enough with RAID :| Is it better then just to set up another mirrored volume. and settle for 6tb usable?

Comment: Mouse over the down arrow; the popup says "*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*".  Downvotes without comment may be presumed to be for at least one of those reasons.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling i was kind of looking for feedback with regards to raid config... which others have answered. thanks anyway

Comment: @MadHatter thanks anyway, i think you've dissuaded me from changing it, at least this question may help someone else with similar question.

Comment: @MadHatter With an array of four disks I'd suggest RAID6 over RAID10, but both definitely have pros and cons. Add one more disk to the RAID6 and you're back to the OP's desired available storage capacity but with better failure modes than a 4-disk RAID5.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling completely agree, though with software RAID-6 you wouldn't want too high a write throughput.  It is, as you say, horses for courses - but both are better than RAID-5.

Comment: @MadHatter OP does say home office NAS / HTPC setup, so I imagine write rates and IOPS requirements are both modest. For that, myself, I'd probably rather have the additional redundancy. But that's a judgment call.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling yet more excellent points!

Comment: if you lose 2 specifics disks on a raid 10 (in the same span) you can lose all your data, even if you use 20 disks or more to do it ... the difference between raid10/5 is performance/space.

Comment: i have a maximum of 4 drives. currently i have 2x 3tb in raid 1. Based on effort to migrate to different raid config. and assuming madm can't manage changing the config without losing data, is the best option to simple set up another 2x3tb raid 1 vol? thanks

Comment: raid5 for space, raid10 for speed and lower chance of data loss. I think linux supports some forms of raid reshaping. mdadm can be configured to send emails and do periodic checks.